# Make Matlab Grid Lines More Visible

Tags: matlab, grid

The grid lines in Matlab 2014b are thin and light, which makes it difficult to see. **Is it possible to increase the visibility of the Matlab grid lines?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only change the thickness of all lines using:

```
ax = gca
ax.LineWidth = 20
```

> LineWidth — Width of axes outline, tick marks, and grid lines
>   0.5 (default) | scalar value Width of axes outline, tick marks, and grid lines, specified as a scalar value in point units. One point
>   equals 1/72 inch.

To make it more visible you can change the color and transparency using:

```
ax = gca
ax.GridLineStyle = '-'
ax.GridColor = 'k'
ax.GridAlpha = 1 % maximum line opacity
```

More details about the editable properties of grid lines can be found here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#zmw57dd0e49371

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Ben's answer, you can change the default parameters of the system so that the changes are applied at all times.

For the case of lines width, you want to use this:

```
set(0,'DefaultLineLineWidth',Some value)
```

Check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) link for the format to use to set default parameters. This applies to pretty much anything you want to change about graphics objects.

Answer (score 1):

This has been bugging me for a while too and Ben's answer finally just helped me figure out that the default transparency of the grid lines is only 0.15. To fix it:

```
ax=gca;
ax.GridAlpha=1;
```